# Embed youtube video into facebook wall when user uses facebook like button

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-opengraph

When a user clicks the facebook like button on my site, a post hits their wall.  I'd like that post to have a video embedded in it from youtube.  Is this possible?

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
    <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/embed/G5T76rIgXPQ" property="og:video" />
    <meta content="560" property="og:video:height" />
    <meta content="349" property="og:video:width" />
    <meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Like button alone won't do that for you.  You'll have to programmatically post the video via FB API.  For examples and docs:

[Programatically add and youtube video to wall post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499107/programatically-add-and-youtube-video-to-wall-post)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#publishing